# How to combine methods uploading file?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django application

And I have a upload functionality. And I have two methods that shows the extracted text:

```
  def filter_verdi_total_number_fruit(self, file_name):
        self.extractingText.extract_text_from_image(file_name)
        regex = r"(\d*(?:\.\d+)*)\s*\W+(?:" + '|'.join(re.escape(word)
                                                       for word in self.extractingText.list_fruit) + ')'
        return re.findall(regex, self.extractingText.text_factuur_verdi[0])

    def filter_verdi_fruit_name(self, file_name):
        self.extractingText.extract_text_from_image(file_name)
        regex = r"(?:\d*(?:\.\d+)*)\s*\W+(" + '|'.join(re.escape(word)
                                                       for word in self.extractingText.list_fruit) + ')'
        return re.findall(regex, self.extractingText.text_factuur_verdi[0])
```

But as you can see. There are some duplicate code. Like:

```
file_name
```

and:

```
re.findall(regex, self.extractingText.text_factuur_verdi[0])
```

So I try to combine this two methods in one method:

```
 def combine_methods(self,  file_name):
        self.filter_verdi_total_number_fruit(file_name) 
        self.filter_verdi_fruit_name(file_name)
```

and then I try to call the combined method in the views.py:

```
  if uploadfile.image.path.endswith('.pdf'):
                    content ='\n'.join(filter_text.combine_methods(uploadfile.image.path))
```

But then I get this error:

```
can only join an iterable
Exception Location:     C:\Users\engel\Documents\NVWA\software\blockchainfruit\main\views.py, line 50, in post
Raised during:  main.views.ReadingFile
```

Question: how can I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have forgotten `return` statement in `combine_methods` function, so it returns None, which cannot be "joined" in `content='\n'.join(filter_text.combine_methods(uploadfile.image.path))`